# Keras: batches not completed

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

This is code of Keras, python. When the code below is ran on Linux mint, all batches aren't completed. It is always stopped at 32nd batch like

```
1/100  .............. ETA 30:00 Loss ..  
2/100 =........... ETA 29:59 Loss ..  
3/100 ==......... ETA 29:58 Loss ..  
.  
.  
.  
32/100 ==....... ETA 25:00 Loss ..
```

(Training stops for unknown reason)

But when this code is ran on Windows, this works as expected until 100th batch. What is causing this behavior?

```python
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.layers.noise import AlphaDropout
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as KTF
import tensorflow as tf
import os.path


f_log = './log'
f_model = './model/dogvscat'
model_yaml = 'dogvscat_model.yaml'
model_filename = 'dogvscat_model.json'
weights_filename = 'dogvscat_model_weights.hdf5'

batch_size = 64
epochs = 15
nb_validation_samples = 100

print('Building model...')


if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(f_model,model_filename)):
    print('Saved parameters found. I will use this file...')
    json_string = open(os.path.join(f_model, model_filename)).read()
    model = model_from_json(json_string)
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.load_weights(os.path.join(f_model,weights_filename))
else:
    print('Saved parameters Not found. Creating new model...')
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('selu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('selu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer='lecun_normal'))
    model.add(Activation('selu'))
    model.add(AlphaDropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(2))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0 / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/validation',
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True)

tb_cb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=f_log, histogram_freq=0)
cp_cb = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath = os.path.join(f_model,weights_filename), monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
cbks = [tb_cb, cp_cb]

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_validation_samples,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples,
    callbacks=cbks
    )

score = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, nb_validation_samples)

print('')
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

json_string = model.to_json()       
open(os.path.join(f_model,model_filename), 'w').write(json_string)      
yaml_string = model.to_yaml()       
open(os.path.join(f_model,model_yaml), 'w').write(yaml_string)      
print('save weights')       
model.save_weights(os.path.join(f_model,weights_filename))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code, you should change your `steps_per_epoch`, `validation_steps` just like below.

```python
history = model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(nb_training_samples/batch_size),
epochs=epochs,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=np.ceil(nb_validation_samples/batch_size),
callbacks=cbks
)
```

On every step your batch_size of samples is used so you need `np.ceil(nb_training_samples/batch_size)` steps for an epoch

Comment: I tried it but got "nb_training_samples is not diefined" error. So I changed it to "nb_validation_samples" but now the steps per epoch are shown as only 2. The steps per epoch shouldn't be as many as nb_validation_samples (like 100)?

Comment: No, steps per epoch equals nb_training_samples / batch_size.
You have to calculate nb_training_samples first

Comment: Maybe it was because I was misunderstanding the steps per epoch must equal number of samples. Actually I was using 2000 samples per class and 64(batch size) * 32 = 2048, so it stopped at 32nd step. Thank you!!